# (xs : Vect n elem) -> Vect (n * 2) elem

Tags: idris

The book [Type Driven Development with Idris](https://www.manning.com/books/type-driven-development-with-idris) presents this exercise:

> Define a possible method that fits the signature:

`two : (xs : Vect n elem) -> Vect (n * 2) elem`

I tried:

```
two : (xs : Vect n elem) -> Vect (n * 2) elem
two xs = xs ++ xs
```

But I got the following error:

```
*One> :r
Type checking ./One.idr
One.idr:9:5:When checking right hand side of two:
Type mismatch between
        Vect (n + n) elem (Type of xs ++ xs)
and
        Vect (mult n 2) elem (Expected type)

Specifically:
        Type mismatch between
                plus n n
        and
                mult n 2
Holes: Hw1.two
```

If I have a Vector of size N, and need a Vector of size N*2, then appending it to itself seems reasonable.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I cannot tell you why your solution does not work. It obviously cannot prove that n + n = n * 2. This works however: 
`
two : (xs : Vect n elem) -> Vect (n * 2) elem
two [] = []
two (x :: xs) = [x,x] ++ two xs
`
Here I do not know why it can prove it.

Comment: Actually, I mis-spoke in stating that this is an exercise from Type Driven Development with Idris - https://forums.manning.com/posts/list/37237.page.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Short answer

Change the type signature to `two : (xs : Vect n elem) -> Vect (n + n) elem`.

### If you really need it that way

Getting to `Vect (n * 2) elem` is a bit complicated. Here:

```
two' : Vect n elem -> Vect (n * 2) elem
two' {n} xs = rewrite multCommutative n 2 in rewrite plusZeroRightNeutral n in xs ++ xs
```

The reason you got that error message is that equality in typechecking is equality after reduction to normal form. `n + n` and `mult n 2` are equal, but their normal forms aren't. (`mult n 2` is what `n * 2` reduces to after resolving the typeclass.)

You can see the definition of `mult` like so:

```
*kevinmeredith> :printdef mult
mult : Nat -> Nat -> Nat
mult 0 right = 0
mult (S left) right = plus right (mult left right)
```

It works by pattern matching on the first argument. Since the first argument in the type signature of `two` is `n`, `mult` can't be reduced at all. `multCommutative` will help us flip it around:

```
*kevinmeredith> :t multCommutative 
multCommutative : (left : Nat) ->
                  (right : Nat) -> left * right = right * left
```

Our best tool to apply that equality is `rewrite`, like in my definition of `two'`. (run `:t replace` at the REPL if you want to see how to do it the hard way) In the `rewrite foo in bar` construction, `foo` is something of type `a = b` and `bar` has the type of the outer expression, but with all `a`s replaced by `b`s.  In my `two'` above, I first used it to change `Vect (n * 2)` to `Vect (2 * n)`. This lets `mult` reduce. If we look at `mult` above, and apply it to `2` i.e. `S (S Z)` and `n`, you get `plus n (mult (S Z) n`, and then `plus n (plus n (mult Z n))`, and then `plus n (plus n Z)`. You don't have to work out the reduction yourself, you can just apply the rewrite and put a hole on the end:

```
two' : Vect n elem -> Vect (n * 2) elem
two' {n} xs = rewrite multCommutative n 2 in ?aaa
```

Then ask Idris:

```
*kevinmeredith> :t aaa
  elem : Type
  n : Nat
  xs : Vect n elem
  _rewrite_rule : plus n (plus n 0) = mult n 2
--------------------------------------
aaa : Vect (plus n (plus n 0)) elem
```

`plus n Z` doesn't reduce because `plus` is defined by recursion on its first argument, just like `mult`. `plusZeroRightNeutral` gets you the equality you need:

```
*kevinmeredith> :t plusZeroRightNeutral 
plusZeroRightNeutral : (left : Nat) -> left + 0 = left
```

I used the same technique with `rewrite` again.

`:search` will let you search the library for inhabitants of a given type. You'll often find someone has done the work of proving things for you.

```
*kevinmeredith> :s (n : Nat) -> n + 0 = n
= Prelude.Nat.multOneLeftNeutral : (right : Nat) ->
                                   fromInteger 1 * right = right


= Prelude.Nat.plusZeroRightNeutral : (left : Nat) ->
                                     left + fromInteger 0 = left


*kevinmeredith> :s (n, m : Nat) -> n * m = m * n
= Prelude.Nat.multCommutative : (left : Nat) ->
                                (right : Nat) -> left * right = right * left
```

(This answer is for Idris version 0.9.20.1)